# Error while including the proteus library - "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout"

Tags: android, proteus

below is the app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation ('com.github.flipkart-incubator:proteus:5.0.0-rc12') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support-v7'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Error -

> Error: Program type already present:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout

complete error - https://gist.github.com/sisogit/055c93ddc08b1e24c6ae0e4c6f1129f0

Tried to exclude some of the libs from the proteus as `exclude` tag, but no help.

Please help.

Steps - 
1. Create empty project in studio.

2. Run >> works normally
3. Add the `implementation ('com.github.flipkart-incubator:proteus:5.0.0-rc12')` and run the project

It will give the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in version `5.0.0-rc14`